# Application crashes when Windows 10 left idle

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, crash-dumps, sysinternals

I'm observing a problem that is getting really difficult to root cause.

My WPF application which is pretty heavy on memory and disk I/O behaves very strangely in the below scenario:

**When the machine and application is left idle for about 15 minutes and more,** and I do some operations on the GUI after that, I notice that the responsiveness really goes down. Everything starts to feel laggy and I notice intermittent white screen (as if system froze). If i continue actions on the white screen, the system eventually reboots.
The event viewer shows the below log:

```
The program <name>.exe version 1.0.0.195 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
Process ID: 19ac
Start Time: 01d5fbf0e001952b
Termination Time: 18
Application Path: D:\Executables\<name>.exe
Report Id: 8f43b0bd-c4a1-45cd-9672-88899ad592fb
Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID: 
 Hang type: Unknown
```

What tools can I use to troubleshoot the issue? Any Sysinternals tool that would do the trick? How should I be approaching this?

**Looks like when the machine is idle for a while, windows start doing something in the background (bookkeeping etc.) and my operations on the GUI further spikes the load on the system.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try and debug the app under VS. Keep your debugger attached, and when the program starts to hang, break in VS and see what function is causing the hang. If the program crashes, report what the VS debugger says the exception code is and where it's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arush. The system where the issue is seen is running the binary in release mode without debug symbols with UWF enabled. When the crash happens, everything is wiped off from the disk.